# Check if an array contains another fields value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one collection of documents that are formatted as follows:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('617d318eb863ee273c66b111'),
  my_object: {
    _id: ObjectId('617d318eb863ee273c66b222')
    //other fields
  },
  exclusion_object: {
    my_arr: ObjectId('617d318eb863ee273c66b222')
    //other fields
  }
}
```

So I need to exclude the documents where `my_object._id` is included in `exclusion_object.my_arr`

I tried (in *$match* stage):

```
{
  $match:{
    'exclusion_object.my_arr': { $nin:['my_object._id','$exclusion_object.my_arr']}
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.. any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- `$in` query operator needs value so we cant use it with `$fieldName`
  `{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }`
- `$in` aggregate operator takes expression also so we can use it with `$fieldName`
  `{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }`
- when aggregate operator is used on `$match` `$expr` operator is needed also

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70143174-m)

```json
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$not": [{"$in": ["$my_object._id", "$exclusion_object.my_arr"]}]}}}])
```